# Can same design patterns be used for web as well as desktop applications for .net

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have been developing web apps in .net for many years now. I have a need to architect a solution for desktop application. Whatare the most common architecture that is used for desktop? what are the factors to be considered? Can the same design patterns be applied for both web as well as desktop? Please don't mark this question as open ended and close it. This would help people with web experience to get some ideas from people who have worked on desktop apps.
Appreciate expert answers on this!

Regards,

Comment: Come with a specific answerable question. Your question is too broad and unclear what do you mean by design pattern and architecture. Everybody can have their own meaning for them. So be specific. We don't know what you mean by design patterns. It is such a broad term that even doesn't makes sense in this context.

Comment: I think you look for MVVM pattern

Comment: @DragoshStoica Not really. OP hasn't given any clue about his UI framework. If it happens to be winforms, then no; winforms and mvvm can't go together(atleast easily).

Comment: sure, but if he use new technologies, it will be WPF or SilverLight (universal apps), and MVVM should be used in this situations

Comment: thanks for taking time to respond! I need to use .net. For ex in web I use MVC and repository pattern, like that which is the best one for win forms? WPF or win forms which one would good? I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is indeed too open, but here are my two cents. I'll share with you my experience when I went from developing for web in ASP.NET Web Forms and MVC to WinForms development.

If you're experienced with web development it would not be very hard for you to jump into desktop application development with .NET. The transition is pretty smooth, thanks to the shared framework. As you advance, you'll encounter many similarities to ASP.NET Web Forms (though most are only on the surface level). After all, this is exactly what Microsoft aimed to achieve at the time - making web development more desktop-like and abstracting the details of the stateless HTTP client-server communication in such a way that the developer doesn't have to think too much about it. This is both the strength and the weakness of ASP.NET Web Forms, as I'm sure you can tell by your own experience.

That being said, on many occasions you'll see the same patterns being used in the application design, namely MVC. You will see similarities in the event handling and in many controls. Fear not, I am sure that you will find that your experience in web development very valuable in desktop development. To me this is a far easier transition than going from desktop to web.

Answer (score 0):

This question is too board and so does my following answer.

Web architecture (client/server) can be used by desktop, but event-driven desktop architecture usually cannot (or harder to) be used by web. So if you want to develop a desktop/web system, use client-server architecture.